# How to return/output JSON objects in the same array?

Tags: python, json

This is my program where when sending an input string of text, the response is each word and how many times it occurs (returned as JSON objects):

```
from swagger_server.models.result import Result  # noqa: E501


def get_concordance(body):  # noqa: E501
    """Calculate

    Post text to generate concordance # noqa: E501

    :param body: Text to be analyzed
    :type body: dict | bytes

    :rtype: Result
    """

    input_text = body.decode('utf-8')

    split_string = (input_text.split())

    def word_count():
        # counts = dict()
        counts = {}

        for word in split_string:
            if word in counts:
                counts[word] += 1
            else:
                counts[word] = 1

        return counts

    try:
        response = {
            "concordance": [
                {
                    "count": word_count(),
                    "token": split_string
                }
            ],
            "input": input_text
        }
    except Exception as error:
        response = {
            "error": repr(error)
        }
    return response
```

Right now the JSON output looks like:

```
{
  "concordance": [
    {
      "count": {
        "The": 1,
        "brown": 2,
        "fox": 1,
        "jumped": 1,
        "log.": 1,
        "over": 1,
        "the": 1
      },
      "token": [
        "The",
        "brown",
        "fox",
        "jumped",
        "over",
        "the",
        "brown",
        "log."
      ]
    }
  ],
  "input": "The brown fox jumped over the brown log."
}
```

However, I am trying to have the output formatted to look like:

```
{
  "concordance": [
    {
      "token": "brown",
      "count": 2
    },
    {
      "token": "fox",
      "count": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "jumped",
      "count": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "log",
      "count": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "over",
      "count": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "the",
      "count": 1
    }
  ],
  "input": "The brown fox jumped over the brown log."
}
```

Does anyone know how I can change my code so that it prints it correctly?
I am not sure how I can separate each word in the list and associate it with its count.
Thank you.

Comment: I posted the actual output first, and the desired output second.

Comment: can you post the sample input

Comment: sample input is `The brown fox jumped over the brown log.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Construct a list of your token-count dictionaries in a list comprehension.

```
def get_concordance(body):  # noqa: E501
    # Documentation omitted for brevity
    input_text = body.decode('utf-8')
    split_string = input_text.split()

    def word_count():
        # counts = dict()
        counts = {}

        for word in split_string:
            if word in counts:
                counts[word] += 1
            else:
                counts[word] = 1

        return counts
    
    try:
        # {"the": 2, "brown": 1}
        counts = word_count()
        # This is the changed part.
        concordance = [{"count": counts[token], "token": token} for token in counts.keys()]
        response = {
            "concordance": concordance,
            "input": input_text,
        }
    except Exception as error:
        response = {
            "error": repr(error)
        }
    return response
```

```
inputs = b"The brown fox jumped over the brown log"
get_concordance(inputs)

{'concordance': [{'count': 1, 'token': 'The'},
  {'count': 2, 'token': 'brown'},
  {'count': 1, 'token': 'fox'},
  {'count': 1, 'token': 'jumped'},
  {'count': 1, 'token': 'over'},
  {'count': 1, 'token': 'the'},
  {'count': 1, 'token': 'log'}],
 'input': 'The brown fox jumped over the brown log'}
```

Comment: The output format is correct, however, it is returning repeat words (i.e. "brown"). I'd like to have the word "brown" listed once, with its current count.

Comment: Current output (with duplicate "brown"): `{
  "concordance": [
    {
      "count": 1,
      "token": "The"
    },
    {
      "count": 2,
      "token": "brown"
    },
    {
      "count": 1,
      "token": "fox"
    },
    {
      "count": 1,
      "token": "jumped"
    },
    {
      "count": 1,
      "token": "over"
    },
    {
      "count": 1,
      "token": "the"
    },
    {
      "count": 2,
      "token": "brown"
    },
    {
      "count": 1,
      "token": "log"
    }
  ],
  "input": "The brown fox jumped over the brown log"
}
`

Comment: @HannahYoussef - fixed it by iterating over the `counts` dictionary instead of the split string.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a relatively simple way to do it that uses the [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counterhttps://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class to simplify things a little bit (and gets rid of the nested-function):

```
import collections
from pprint import pprint
#from swagger_server.models.result import Result  # noqa: E501


def get_concordance(body):  # noqa: E501
    """Calculate

    Post text to generate concordance # noqa: E501

    :param body: Text to be analyzed
    :type body: dict | bytes

    :rtype: Result
    """

    input_text = body.decode('utf-8')
    split_string = input_text.split()
    word_counts = collections.Counter(split_string)

    pairs = [{'token': token, 'count': count}
                for token, count in zip(split_string, word_counts.values())]
    response = {
        "concordance": pairs,
        "input": input_text
    }
    return response



if __name__ == '__main__':

    body = b'The brown fox jumped over the log'
    resp = get_concordance(body)
    pprint(resp, sort_dicts=False)
```

Output:

```
{'concordance': [{'token': 'The', 'count': 1},
                 {'token': 'brown', 'count': 1},
                 {'token': 'fox', 'count': 1},
                 {'token': 'jumped', 'count': 1},
                 {'token': 'over', 'count': 1},
                 {'token': 'the', 'count': 1},
                 {'token': 'log', 'count': 1}],
 'input': 'The brown fox jumped over the log'}
```